# Map function - Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `[a]'

Tags: haskell

this is an exercice :

```
-- Implement the function sumRights which sums all Right and discard Left
-- Examples:
--   sumRights [Right 1, Left "bad value", Right 2]  ==>  3
--   sumRights [Left "bad!", Left "missing"]         ==>  0
```

My idea was, as a first step, to transform the list with map into a list of integers only.
I wrote the following :

```
transformListToInt :: [Either a Int] -> Int
transformListToInt list = map f list
    where f (Right b) = b 
          f (Left  c) = 0
```

But it gives me the following error :

```
* Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `[a]'
* In the expression: map f list
  In an equation for `sumRights':
      sumRights list
        = map f list
        where
            f (Right b) = b
            f (Left c) = c
```

Could someone help me to understand why I get this error ?
(the initial problem is not so important, I could solve it differently)

Comment: Your error message doesn't quite match your code. Your code defines `transformListToInt`, but the error message says you are defining `sumRights`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to sum the list in the end:

```
transformListToInt :: [Either a Int] -> Int
transformListToInt list = sum $ map f list
    where f (Right b) = b 
          f (Left  c) = 0
```

A shorter way to write the same would be:

```
transformListToInt = sum . map (fromRight 0)
```

or even shorter:

```
transformListToInt = sum . rights
```

(both ways require importing [`Data.Either`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html))

Comment: I thought the issue was in the definition of f function, so I was completely 'tunnel vision'ed.
Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

`map` turns a list `[x0,x1,...]` into another list `[f x0, f x1, ...]`. It can not produce an `Int` as your type claims, so the compiler complains.

Since your `map` generates a value of type `[Int]`, you need to transform that list into the sum of its elements (use `sum`).